# Is there a way to save a webpage page with Mendeley Webimporter?

Tags: citations, reference-managers

We can save references from the page, but it will be great to save the entire page. As it may happen to the page is not accessible anymore later.

Comment: would printing the page to a pdf (CTRL+P) and saving that pdf work for you? I found this more convenient then saving actual HTML Code (CTRL+S), as the latter would produce multiple files and javascript executions might lead to a different view now or later.

Comment: Yeah, that is definitely an option I have been considering. It is just a two/three steps process. I was thinking there should be a way to do that automatically with Mendeley. Thinking about it now, we can actually save directly the pdf in a folder that is synchronized with Mendeley. However not sure if Mendeley can then correctly extract the references from the pdf.

Answer (score 1):

When you click on the Mendeley plug-in icon in the browser while you are on the webpage you want to save, it gives you the option to save the webpage too 
  [image]

This example is from Google Chrome with Mendeley Web Importer.

Comment: I am using the same Chrome extension, but this will only save the reference to the page, not the page content.